What happens when changing “/etc/passwd” permission to 744?
For educational purposes I changed /etc/passwd permission to 744; originally its 644. Even I know it's not executable, the system wasn't able to solve users name and Gnome didn't lunch until I changed it back to 644 from TTY. Like if 744 prevented others from reading the file, why did that happen?
I was testing the issue on RHEL 9.4 as a guest on KVM, host is Ubuntu 24.
P.S. I'm still learning and preparing for Red Hat Certified System Administrator (RHCSA), and I apologize for my poor English.

ps. im still learning and preparing for RHCSA, and i apologize for my poor English

My hunch is that the issues is that the /usr/bin/passwd application runs with souid, and marking the /etc/passwd file as executable is breaking the applications ability to work with the passwd and shadow files. not entirely clear on all the details, but thats where I'd start

A long shot - but I wonder if this relates to selinux?

@davidgo i checked SELinux for denials related to the /etc/passwd with ausearch , journalctl and there is non. also there is no denials related to /etc/passwd in /var/log/audit/audit.log
i'm sorry if i'm missing something, this is why i'm here asking.
